# Remote control over about 8-10 PCs

Tags: windows-10, remote-access, remote-desktop

I'm looking for a software to have remote control over about 8-10 PCs. It's for my business and I prefer (of course) freeware.

I've seen **Remote Utilities** and it allows a control of up to 10 PCs even for commercial purposes. Can you recommend this software?

I also know **Team Viewer** and with about 25$/month it's also ok but "all" I need is WoL and control over the client desktop.

OS is Windows 10 Professional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on what sort of remote control you want, I've used the following:

1. Windows RDP (Remote Desktop Protocol) - you log in to the remote workstation, the user sees the lock screen. This isn't really intended for remote assistance. Included with Windows.
2. VNC - There are several implementations of this, ostensibly interoperable, but I've never actually had 'mismatched' implementations at opposite ends of a connection. This is suitable for remote assistance; you connect to the remote computer and the screen is mirrored, so that you see what the remote user sees.
3. Dameware Mini Remote Control - much like VNC, functionality is extended. Does not need pre-installation; can remote-install itself. Commercial only.

Comment: While Dameware and RDP are both Windows only, I believe VNC is available for Linux and MacOS, and thus there is the possibility of using it cross-platform.

Comment: Thank you, will have a look at it! Obviously I missed another important aspect: The user at the client PC must not see such a lock screen relatively something more "user friendly" would be better.

Comment: Then RDP isn't going to be your answer. Dameware does allow you to lock out the user's keyboard and mouse if needed; I don't know if VNC has that facility.

Comment: VNC is even a bit more expensive than TeamViewer. Dameware is not quite clear, there is the price of 1 technician which is 215 $. Is it per year or once?

Comment: There are free VNCs out there; I just don't remember the specific implementation names. As I recall, Dameware is a purchase-once, not a SAAS or annual license.

Comment: A quick google finds TightVNC and UltraVNC/UVNC as freebies.